# Cost breakdown for a Cloud Data Lake Implementation

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, data-lake

We have a client in need of a data lake on the cloud.

We need to provide the client the chance to breakdown costs between their areas in just one AWS Account.

We are talking about query and data transfer costs also.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A. If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/cloud

Comment: Well, I thought of a way to identify costs from the cloudtrail and cloudwatch, this could be achieved by programming the use but I wish to know if there are other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this, at least most of it, with so calle dcost allocation tags:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html

It is a way of assigning tags to resources that allows you to split up costs later on in the [Cost explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/), allowing you to see a projects or "areas" share of the overall cost.

But not everything can be tagged yet, so there might be "blind spots" where you do not have data. You could split up the remaining difference evenly between all areas.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also have this whitepaper https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/cost-modeling-data-lakes.pdf about modeling cost in a data lake for AWS but like you said there could be blind spots, I'm thinking of data querys and data transfer out.

Comment: I've also found that workspaces are a great way to segment costs in Athena, plus the requester-pays model so in S3.